# Can SKEmitterNode particles be rotated around their X and Y axes?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to use SpriteKit and SKEmitterNodes to create a confetti effect for my app. To give it a more 3-dimensional feel (kind of similar to the full-screen effect in iMessage below), I was hoping it was possible to randomly rotate the particles around their X and Y axes. However, I can only figure out how to do plain rotations around the Z axis.

[image: Notice how the particles rotate around all axes]

I know SpriteKit is not meant for 3D effects, but since it seems like this particular effect can easily be achieved using 2D affine transforms, I was hoping this was possible somehow.

If it is not possible to do this using SpriteKit, I would LOVE to get some pointers on how to recreate an effect similar to the one above using SceneKit instead.

Comment: SKShader..... probably only way

Comment: Not sure why this got closed as a duplicate.... this is about SKEmitterNodes and sprite kit, not ui kit with a calayer